# No link template Error on saving node having field referencing a particular taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

I am getting the following error on saving a node.

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\UndefinedLinkTemplateException: No link template '' found for the 'taxonomy_term' entity type in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->toUrl() (line 196 of /opt/app-root/src/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityBase.php).
```

I realised that this happens to any content type having a field referencing a particular taxonomy vocabulary. However I am not able to understand why this error is triggered.

Comment: Are you trying to link to the vocabulary somewhere?

Comment: Yes I have created an entity reference field to reference the vocabulary. This field has been added to the Content type.

Comment: I believe the error is because something is trying to link to the entity (taxonomy vocab) referenced in your field, but taxonomy vocabularies (and other config entities?) don't provide a canonical path like regular content entities. I would make sure that you're not trying to "link to the referenced entity" anywhere.

Comment: This does happen if we switch to another vocabulary which adds to the complexity.

Comment: It _does_ or _does not_?

Comment: Sorry I meant 'does not'